# How to share Ethernet through USB tether as WiFi hotspot?

Tags: wifi-hotspot, usb-tethering, reverse-tether

I have a situation where I have internet via Ethernet on a Windows PC and I want to share it via WiFi but said PC has no WiFi card.

So the idea is to use USB tethering (RNDIS) and then use a WiFi hotspot to share the RNDIS. Android phone is rooted and has Termux, so tools like `iptables` should be accessible.

The PC with the internet could run Linux too and run `iptables`, but I prefer Windows if possible.

Comment: USB WiFi dongles are cheap. Why exactly you want to go that route? BTW, reverse USB tethering which is what you apparently want doesn't require anything special or even root: https://www.howtogeek.com/117118/how-to-connect-your-android-to-your-pcs-internet-connection-over-usb/ PS - I agree as it being off-topic here.

Comment: gniretet worked but i had to also use vpnhotspot: https://github.com/Mygod/VPNHotspot which needs root to bridge ap0 for hotspot and tun0 for vpn. ping does not work also. but its very unstable

Comment: btw i cant use a dongle coz its office computer. only usb cable

Comment: *its office computer* If so then very likely you shouldn't try what you're asking here anyway. Ask your IT department.